# R SpatialPolygonsDataFrame merge with Regular Dataframe

Tags: r, visualization, geospatial, polygons, choropleth

I have been working on creating a choropleth using ggplot and downloaded the country/county file as a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

```
countyData <- read.csv('County_data.csv')
readin =  readRDS('IRL_adm1.rds')
```

I then created a base map using ggplot

```
basemap = ggplot(readin) +theme_minimal()+  
  geom_polygon( aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
                color = "white",  
                fill = "#9C9797")+ 
  coord_map()
```

I had no problems so far and a map was created but I wanted to combine some data I had with the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame  to be able to color each county on the map

I tried merging the two using merge -

```
combine= merge(readin,countyData, by="NAME_1")
```

and then creating a final choropleth -

```
final_map = ggplot(combine)+ theme_minimal()+
  geom_polygon( aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill= combine$Data),   #### I also tried combine@data$Data - but got the same error message ## Data being the vector I want to use to color the counties
                color = "grey", alpha = 1/5) +
  coord_map()+
  scale_fill_distiller(name = "Number of queries per county",  legend
                       palette = "Spectral")+ 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

but when I try to show the map I get the following error -

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (169288): x, y, group, fill
```

The 'combine' is of the right datatype -- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and when I check combine@data the 'Data' vector has been added to it but I am not sure why it looks like the wrong length

Comment: `?sp::merge` - returns a spatial object. Try setting the `x` as the spatial object itself, and not just the data `combine= merge(readin,countyData, by="NAME_1")`

Comment: you can try `countyData@Data= left_join(countyData@Data, readin,by="NAME_1")`

Comment: I made that change and tried to run and it gives me the message 'Region defined for each Polygons' so I try to generate the map and it gives me 'Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Data' not found'. I then tried to identify it with combine$Data or combine@data$Data but getting the following error for both - 'Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (169288): x, y, group, fill'

Comment: Update your answer to reflect what you've done; we can't see it exactly from this comment.